# UTF-8 coding question (what is the last unicode character)

Tags: utf-8, internationalization

we are opening up our application to allow support for multiple languages.  one of the problems we have encountered along the way is a feature we provide our customers.  Imagine for a moment the user is presented with 3 fields.

1. All customers is a toggle
2. From Customer Name is a field they can type in
3. To Customer Name is a field they can type in.

what happens from the user experience standpoint is if you select all customers "from" and "to" are disabled

what happens in the code is if the customer selects "all customers" we look for all customer records that have customer names greater than or equal to "" (blank) and less than or equal to "}}}}}}}}}}}}" (which works fine in ANSI).

when we put a chinese character in the first letter of the name this does not work since the code for the Chinese glyph is greater than "}".  Is there a character in UTF-8 that is "the last character" so I could replace it?

We are intending on supporting multiple languages so if the solution only works for Chinese it won't help us.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: Why do you compare to a empty string or the string `"}}}}}}}}}}}}"` anyways? Why don’t you just select all customers?

Comment: The direct answer to your question is U+10FFFD, which is a user-defined character from the Supplementary Private Use Area B.  It appears that U+10FFFE and U+10FFFF are not allowed, probably to avoid problems with UTF-32 or UTF-16 and byte-order marks, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for actually answering the question. Follow up question: How can I know for sure that U+10FFFD is the last character in UTF-8? What makes it so?

Answer (score 3):

When "all customers" is selected run a query without any conditions on customer name.

Yes, this means a new, alternate path of execution. Yes, it's not "smart".

At the same time it will be a lot more readable and easier to troubleshoot later. KISS

Comment: this would work but we end up with several paths (not just 2).  All customers, from customer selected and to customer not selected, to customer selected but from customer not selected, from and to customer selected.  

the other problem is this code is everywhere (ugh) so it isn't one fix and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be simpler to create a base select statement with all other conditions and then add the from/to conditions based on whether the from/to fields were filled in or not? Something like this:

```
sql = "select a,b,c from users where c = 123";
if(!from.empty())
   sql += " and name >= '" + from + "'";
if(!to.empty())
   sql += " and name < '" + to + "'";
```

Comment: WARNING: Copy & paste of this code with no additional consideration would lead to a SQL injection vuln.  The idea of extending the query based on input is reasonable, it's just that the implementation is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CUSTOMERNAME IS NOT NULL instead? That would allow any range of characters without worrying about what's the first and last character in any particular text encoding.

Comment: thanks for the comments everyone.  as the first comment suggested reworking the code into multiple code paths can work (one for all customers one for from and to customer filled out).   this is sort of the same thought and I may end up here to solve the problem and for efficiency sake.

Answer (score 0):

I would rework the logic of the application so that you don't have to search for the names of the customers in order to get references to them.

Simply add all customers to the list of customers if the "all customers" switch is toggled on.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan's comment is absolutely correct, and helpful to those who come here for a direct answer to the question in the title.

Technically speaking, **the last possible Unicode character according to the currently defined standard (set by the Unicode Consortium) is `u+10FFFD`**

However, the last "practical" Unicode character that you might be looking for is likely to be `u+FFFF`. This is the last character in "Basic Multilingual Plane".

To elaborate a bit and apply it to this question:

Unicode is defined by the Unicode Consortium and is split into seventeen "planes" (as of this writing). Each plane consists of 65,532 possible characters for a total of 1,114,112 possible characters in the entire unicode standard.

The first plane is called the "Basic Multilingual Plane" and is sufficient for the vast majority of use cases. This consists of the codes u+0000-u+FFFF

Or in other words, the first 65,532 characters defined in Unicode (plus 4 special noncharacters at the end). This encompasses all 8 and 16-bit unicode chars.

This first plane is mostly "full" and encompasses the vast majority of possible characters and symbols that could be used in all modern (and many ancient) languages.

One prominent exception to this is emoji, which are spread across both the Basic Multilingual Plane and the Supplementary Multilingual Plane (u+10000–​u+1FFFF).

There are more 'supplementary planes' which are also usually mostly empty but contain important symbols (usually ancient, rare and historic symbols, useful especially in academia).

So, generally speaking if you are just trying to encompass all modern languages the Basic Multilingual Plane should be sufficient. If your use case involves emoji, or if you want to be 100% sure that you can support most rare, archaic and/or ancient languages, then you may want to go all the way to the end of the Supplementary Multilingual Plane (`u+1FFFF`). If for some reason you need to support everything, then the range is from `u+0000` to `u+10FFFD`, but it is worth noting that this will be mostly empty (if you choose a random char, for example) and also includes large unassigned and private blocks as well.

See also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)
[Unicode.org technical site](https://unicode.org/main.html)
[Unicode.org Calculator for Calculating char sets](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp)